# Unable to install any packages in R-Studio

Tags: r, macos, install.packages

I am running [r-studio](/questions/tagged/r-studio) `version 1.1.463` on [macos](/questions/tagged/macos) `Yosemite Version 10.10.5`. My laptop is from early 2015. Whenever I try to install any packages in R-Studio it gives me this error message:

Apologies for I am a complete n00b but I am not sure if this means the packages did get downloaded. If they did, where can I find them and what do I need to do to have them installed in R-Studio? I do not have a C compiler and am not sure I need one.

> ```
>     =============================================
>
>     install.packages('reshape')
>     also installing the dependencies ‘Rcpp’, ‘plyr’
>
>     Warning in install.packages :
>       unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/3.2
>     Packages which are only available in source form, and may need compilation
>       of C/C++/Fortran: ‘Rcpp’ ‘plyr’ ‘reshape’
>     Do you want to attempt to install these from sources?
>     y/n: y
>     installing the source packages ‘Rcpp’, ‘plyr’, ‘reshape’
>
>     trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Rcpp_1.0.4.tar.gz'
>     Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2750216 bytes (2.6 MB)
>     ==================================================
>     downloaded 2.6 MB
>
>     trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/plyr_1.8.6.tar.gz'
>     Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 401191 bytes (391 KB)
>     ==================================================
>     downloaded 391 KB
>
>     trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/reshape_0.8.8.tar.gz'
>     Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 42558 bytes (41 KB)
>     ==================================================
>     downloaded 41 KB
>
>     * installing *source* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
>     ** package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>     ** libs
>     xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install. Choose an option in the
> dialog to download the command line developer tools.
>     ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’
>     * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/Rcpp’
>     Warning in install.packages :
>       installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status
>     ERROR: dependency ‘Rcpp’ is not available for package ‘plyr’
>     * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/plyr’
>     Warning in install.packages :
>       installation of package ‘plyr’ had non-zero exit status
>     ERROR: dependency ‘plyr’ is not available for package ‘reshape’
>     * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/reshape’
>     Warning in install.packages :
>       installation of package ‘reshape’ had non-zero exit status
>
>     The downloaded source packages are in
>       ‘/private/var/folders/zp/18zxxbcs5cncbn98lr6zcptc0000gn/T/RtmpQ6Hg59/downloaded_packages’
> ```

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Hi what is your R.version.string ?

Comment: Perhaps consider asking on: https://community.rstudio.com/

Comment: try updating R to 3.6. and RStudio to 1.2.5

Comment: What happens if the you run: `library(reshape)`?  If you don't get an error message then it is properly installed.

Comment: R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)

Comment: > library(reshape)
Error in library(reshape) : there is no package called ‘reshape’

Comment: I am unable to upgrade because my laptop is 32-bit and RStudio 1.2.5 requires 64-bit?

Answer (score 0):

- Note the error: "no developer tools were found at
  '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install."
- Note this is also
  stated from R studio's dependencies page: "The core software
  development utilities required for R package development can be
  obtained by installing the Command Line Tools for XCode. You can do
  this in one of two ways."
  [source](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486498-Package-Development-Prerequisites)

You need to install command line developer tools. Launch your terminal and do:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Then retry the install.